# Android Expandable Listview with swipe Left and Right

Tags: android, expandablelistview, swipe

I want to develop an Expandable List View with Left to Right and Right to Left swipe. I have already implemented Right to Left swipe but unable to implement other swipe

Comment: see this link https://github.com/tycallen/SwipeMenu-Expandable-ListView

Comment: The library under this demo implements only right to left swipe but not the other swipe

Comment: why this question be downvote.